# IE Options: How to enable Proxy settings sections

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, regedit

[image: Proxy server section is disabled in IE]![Hi all,

Though I am having admin rights, I could not enable the proxy settings. I've tried using regedit but still could not enable this.

Also, I need to add few more URLs that needs to be added in the proxy.

Please help us why the proxy settings section is not enabled?][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm3TQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Read this Doc..**[Configure Internet Explorer to use a proxy server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/135982)**